# How does custom Plutus data type map to cardano-cli --tx-in-datum-file content?

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, on-chain, datum

Let's say I have validator, which checks datum against two numbers, hash, time and a string and there are some funds locked at this script address and I would like to unlock these funds using `cardano-cli --tx-in-datum-file...` by providing datum file. Inside source code I have a custom data type like so:

```
data CustomDatum = CustomDatum
    { num1 :: Integer
    , num2 :: Integer
    , hash1 :: PubKeyHash
    , time1 :: POSIXTime
    , string1 :: String
    }
    deriving Show

PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''VestingDatum
```

What are the rules to form correct datum file?

How should typed and not typed datum file look like to match my `CustomDatum` inside Plutus script?

How are values mapped between datum file and custom data inside Plutus script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a haskell executable that will convert any of your custom data types to the right JSON format :
https://github.com/OnChainLabs/Martify/blob/main/app/datum-json.hs

In this file we convert the type `NFTSale` which is defined like so :

```
data NFTSale = NFTSale
    { nSeller    :: !PubKeyHash
    , nPrice     :: !Integer
    , nCurrency  :: !CurrencySymbol
    , nToken     :: !TokenName
    } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
```

But it works for any other data type.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a working example with more than one parameter. I still don't understand underlying principles, but at least here is something to start working with:

```
data CustomDatum = CustomDatum
    { num1 :: Integer
    , num2 :: Integer
    }
    deriving Show

PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''CustomDatum [('CustomDatum, 0)]

-- mkValidator :: Datum -> Redeemer -> ScriptContext -> ()
{-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
mkValidator :: CustomDatum -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator dat () ctx = traceIfFalse "Numbers are missing" numbersAreCorrect
  where
    numbersAreCorrect :: Bool
    numbersAreCorrect = ((num1 dat) == 24) && ((num2 dat) == 42)
```

Example datum

```
{
    "constructor":0,
    "fields":
    [
        {
            "int":24
        },
        {
            "int":42
        }
    ]
}
```

Example redeemer

```
{ "constructor": 0, "fields":[] }
```

Comment: And as for the `PubKeyHash`, `"bytes":"25e1081f483086365f62fa37618ad6c4768864806fc874b56abe59d7"` works